# Featured image in custom post is being disabled

Tags: custom-post-types, php, posts, functions

I'm trying to create a custom post as a plugin and so far I'm having some trouble trying to enable featured image on my custom post type. Right now I have created two custom post types but the problem is that whenever I tried activating both of them the other custom post type featured image will be disabled. So far I cannot identify the root cause and also tried looking for answers on google

Here is the code I have been working on.

1st Custom Post Type (Slides)

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Slides Custom Post Plugin
Description: Custom post plugin for Slides custom post
*/
?>
<?php
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ *
 * SLIDES CUSTOM POST
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

function slides () {

// Set UI labels for Custom Post Type
    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Slides', 'Post Type General Name', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Slides', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Slides', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Slides', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Slides', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Slide', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Slide', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Add Slide', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Slide', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Slide', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search Slide', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Not Found', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'twentythirteen' ),
    );

// Set other options for Custom Post Type

    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'Slide', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'description'         => __( 'Slide', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        // Features this CPT supports in Post Editor
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', ),
        // You can associate this CPT with a taxonomy or custom taxonomy.
        'taxonomies'          => array('category', 'post_tag'),
        /* A hierarchical CPT is like Pages and can have
        * Parent and child items. A non-hierarchical CPT
        * is like Posts.
        */
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 4,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page',
    );

    // Registering your Custom Post Type
    register_post_type( 'slides', $args );
}

/* Hook into the 'init' action so that the function
* Containing our post type registration is not
* unnecessarily executed.
*/

add_action( 'init', 'slides', 1 );

/* Enable Featured Image */

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'slides_featured_image');
function slides_featured_image() {
        add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post', 'page', 'slides' ) );
}
?>
```

2nd Custom Post Type (Articles)

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: News & Press Custom Plugin
Description: Custom post plugin for News and Press custom post
*/
?>
<?php
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ *
 * NEWS PRESS CUSTOM POST
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

function news_press () {

// Set UI labels for Custom Post Type
    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'News & Press Release', 'Post Type General Name', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'News & Press Release', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'News & Press', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent News & Press Release', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Articles', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Article', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Article', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Add Article', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Article', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Article', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search Article', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Not Found', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'twentythirteen' ),
    );

// Set other options for Custom Post Type

    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'News & Press Release', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'description'         => __( 'News & Press Release', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        // Features this CPT supports in Post Editor
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', ),
        // You can associate this CPT with a taxonomy or custom taxonomy.
        'taxonomies'          => array('category', 'post_tag'),
        /* A hierarchical CPT is like Pages and can have
        * Parent and child items. A non-hierarchical CPT
        * is like Posts.
        */
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 4,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page',
    );

    // Registering your Custom Post Type
    register_post_type( 'news_press', $args );
}

/* Hook into the 'init' action so that the function
* Containing our post type registration is not
* unnecessarily executed.
*/

add_action( 'init', 'news_press', 1 );


/* Enable Featured Image */

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'news_press_featured_image');
function news_press_featured_image() {
        add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post', 'page', 'news_press' ) );
}
?>
```

Comment: you use `add_theme_support` twice, the second instance overwrites what you set in the first instance.

Comment: Is there a way to enable featured image for both plug-ins?

Comment: you can add theme support without specifying the post types, the 2nd argument is optional. any post type that registers with thumbnail support will have featured images enabled.